# Most efficient way of sending pixel data from Java to OpenGL with alpha component

Tags: java, opengl, bufferedimage

I'm looking for the most efficient (CPU, not memory) way of packing 4-component pixel data contained in a BufferedImage into a format that OpenGL can use.

As far as I can tell, on the Java side, there is *TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR* and *TYPE_INT_ARGB* and on the GL side there is *GL_RGBA* and *GL_BGRA*. Notice that this implies remapping the alpha component. Currently to go from Java to GL I do something like:

```
int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
for (int i=0;i<w;i++)
    for (int j=0;j<h;j++)
{
    int col = image.getRGB(i, j);
    data.put(4*(j*w+i), (byte)((col >> 16) & 0xff));
    data.put(4*(j*w+i)+1, (byte)((col >> 8) & 0xff));
    data.put(4*(j*w+i)+2, (byte)((col >> 0) & 0xff));
    data.put(4*(j*w+i)+3, (byte)((col >> 24) & 0xff));
}
```

where data is a *ByteBuffer* that will then be sent to one of the *glTexture* methods with *GL_RGBA* format.

I'm not really looking for slight tweaks on the above code (unless you think they can have a significant impact), but a way to avoid remapping entirely. Or at least to avoid the color conversions in *getRGB*. For example, when dealing with *TYPE_3BYTE_BGR* in Java, I can send it directly to *GL_BGR* and fill a buffer with:

```
data.put(((DataBufferByte)image.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData());
```

Comment: Does this really need to be efficient? Texture uploading is usually done only once when the level loads. Remember the two rules of optimization.

Comment: if you send ABGR big endian to RGBA little endian then you have it fixed

Comment: Well... It's lame, but you could do it in the shader. However, I do not recommend that, I think it might decrease performance.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo This is meant as an application independent question. It's just something that has always bugged me.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Is there a HW accelerated way of doing that in GL? Care to make an answer out of it?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux It is one way indeed. But I would like a fixed-pipeline solution I could retrofit to some old code.

Comment: Use `TYPE_INT_ARGB`, wrap `image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()` into a `ByteBuffer` swap the byteOrder and you have BGRA order (oh, I thought I was clever, and now notice this is basically what @ratchetfreak said...).

Comment: @haraldK Won't that just be the CPU doing the remapping, though? I will give it a try and see if it speeds things up, thanks.

Comment: @haraldK And won't that give me an upside down image?

Comment: @schmop You're right (probably faster than what you have, but it still is remapping). I should have read the question more carefully. BufferedImages always orders rasters top-down, so it should work just like your `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` example case.

Comment: In fact you asking to do something in less then linear amount of time?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I think that would be impossible. Just something faster that avoids _getRGB_.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo That kind of thinking is why a lot of modern games have unnecessarily long load screens ;) Of course it should be efficient (particularly considering how trivial packing into a driver-friendly format is)!

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Big, triple-A 3D games? Maybe. Small, indie games being developed by people posting on StackOverflow? Unlikely. Plus this is where the second rule of optimization comes in.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Are you saying small indie games shouldn't be optimized? And I'm not asking this for a game btw, Java2D isn't a particularly popular tech in that sector :) I've been asked to try to improve the user experience on some old software. That transfer to texture used to incur a 5 second freeze. I got it down to 1 and now I'm wondering if I can make it unnoticeable.

Comment: @schmop I'm not saying that they shouldn't be optimized; I'm saying that you should stick to [the two (or three) rules of optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization); that is, make it work, and only then do you optimize where you really need to. Uploading textures happens very infrequently and there's not much gain in spending time optimizing it, although I admit that a 5 second freeze is pretty bad.

Comment: @schmop: Do you need the texture image data to be available for use immediately? If you can structure your situation so that you can wait a couple of extra frames while you upload the texture in the background, Pixel Buffer Objects will remove that 1-5 second hitch per-texture completely. The key is you have to write your software so you don't try to ***use*** the texture until the upload is complete.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Yes but in this case that would impact other parts of the software which is beyond the scope of what I'm supposed to do. There's no budget for testing either so I really can't take the risk of breaking anything. Honestly, I've moved on to other stuff but I would have liked a answer to this, though. It just seems weird that by default you can't just store regular 32 bit RGBA. Maybe I should ask that specific question instead? Anyways, thanks for the advice and time, I appreciate it.